# error while installing pg module with npm

Tags: node.js, postgresql, npm

I'm using latest node.js version 0.10.26 and I got these errors when I tried installing postgres module with

```
npm install pg
```

[image]
Though It installed successfully yet I don't know what this means.
Help needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Visual Studio's compiler emits different warnings to gcc, so it'll complain in places where gcc won't, and vice versa.

Many open source developers don't test on Windows with MSVC or d so as little as possible. So they'll usually not see such warnings during regular development.

Most warnings like this are actually harmless - for example, assignment from `size_t` to `int` only matters if the value can ever be large enough to fit in `size_t` but not fit in `int`. They indicate *potential* problems in the code, but most often not real problems that'll impact normal operation.

So - I wouldn't worry overly. Report them to the Pg gem developers so they know they happen. Beyond that, you should be fine. There aren't any really serious warnings like uninitialized variable use there, they're all type cast and conversion warnings.